# Can I use mapcontrol for silverlight after key expired for own map?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dictionary, bing-maps

I am using mapcontrol from Microsoft (primary for Bing map) in silverlight application.
I have trial key.
Is possible to use mapcontrol after expired key for my own map?
Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Microsoft licensing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols/thread/f235f835-c2a4-4eef-8d34-dae633bfb7c6

"No, you need a new Bing Maps key. Trial and developer accounts can only have 1 key so you will either need to get and enterprise license or create a new account. If this application is being used for internal use, asset tracking, or a high volume website you will need an enterprise license. You can contact the licensing team at maplic@microsoft.com"